# IOS Parse SDK Push notification at location with radius

Tags: ios, parse-platform, location

I'm using Parse SDK to push notification.
I sending push notification with a point and radius to users. I want user only receive notification when user go to in radius (Background and killed is ok).
Please tell me how do it?

Comment: Not really sure what your asking here, do you think you can go into a little more detail? You want users to only receive a push notification in a specific area?

Comment: Yes, that's right Jack.